Variable delay in Delay block
Is there a way to apply a variable delay in the delay block? I want to set the delay to zero if a condition is true. I tried to do it with a variable but this is not accapted in the Delay time field.
Many thanks for any help in advance!

you can definitely do it with a variable... for a condition you can do something like on the delay time section:
condition ? 0 : somethingelse

